# Inserting a new managed object in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am new to Core Data and I feel that I don't get a hang of it. When you are going to create a new managed object you have to use the method that I pasted in at the bottom from the NSEntityDescription class.

Now is this object registered in the context, it is right? Why do you have the `insertObject:` in NSManagedContext then? It works without invoking that method after using the one in `NSEntityDescription`. Could somebody explain?

**NSManagedContext**

```
insertObject:
```

**NSEntityDescription**

```
+ (id)insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create NSManagedObject with `nil` context and then decide whether you want to add it to context or not.
You may also like this: [Is there a way to instantiate a NSManagedObject without inserting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3868514/730701)

Comment: Ah, so if you create the instance with nil as context, then you later pass it to the insertObject?

Comment: But if that is not the intended use as some of them points out, why do Apple provide the method? Or is passing `nil` as a context normal?

Comment: I use it all the time without any problems. The method may be useful when you have more than one context. Then you can decide which one to save.

Comment: Okey, but if you use the NSEntityDescription method you already have registered the returned object with a context and you don't invoke the insertObject: in NSManagedContext right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only use insertObject: when the context is nil.