# Setting Core Data Object to nil

Tags: ios, core-data

I am not sure about this, but does setting a core data object to nil, deletes it from Core Data. For Example:

```
MyObject *obj = [MyObject fetchFromCoreDataWithID:objectID];
obj = nil;
```

Does this deletes that object from Core Data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The object is only a representation of what is in your CoreData store. If you want to delete the object you must do this:

```
NSError *saveError = nil;
[_managedObjectContext deleteObject:obj];
[_managedObjectContext save:&saveError];
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

You need to do the following to delete it:

```
[managedObjectContext deleteObject:obj]
```

[See the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html) for more detail.

Comment: This only marks object for deletion. The data is still present until the context is saved.

Comment: True. I was trying to provide a literal version of `obj = nil` that would work; as you say this does not affect the disk representation.

Comment: P.S. You can check if object is mark for deletion with `isDeleted` method call .)

Answer (score 1):

No. To delete check out [deleteObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your `NSManagedObject` without adding it to `NSManagedObjectContext`. Then you don't need to delete it at all. See this for more details: [Inserting a new managed object in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10732785/730701).