# NSManagedObjectContext insertObject - string stored as null

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

i want to insert a previously created NSManagedObject which has some string attributes into my NSManagedObjectContext via the insertObject method. This seems to work without error but when i reload the saved object again all my string attributes are null.

I have created my entity with:

```
[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:description 
         insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

Thanks for any constructive feedback.

Comment: Not enough information-- show us some code. There's no inherent reason why the string would be nil unless you never set a value for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advisable to insert a "previously created" managed object because it is much more robust to insert it during creation.

If you want to **copy** a managed object (i.e. "insert it again") effectively creating **two instances** of it in the persistent store, you will have to create a new one and then copy the all the attributes.

It is certainly more reasonable to *insert the object into the context* and then *delete it* if desired. It is just the much more intuitive and documented way to achieve what you want.

I strongly advise against creating a context-less managed object in your usage case!

Comment: That is not true. It's possible to create a managed object that is not inserted into any managed object context. In fact this is exactly what the code snippet in the question does. By passing `nil` as the context argument, you get a managed object that's not inserted in any context. You can later insert it into a context, provided that the entity exists in the model that the context is using.

Comment: OK, you are right. But that begs the question if this is an appropriate design pattern. Seeing that some attributes are not persisted correctly, probably not.

Comment: I've used it for a discardable edit controller-- when the user asks to create a new entry, initialize a non-inserted managed object to store the data they enter. If they save changes, insert the object, and if they cancel, just discard the object.

Comment: Good case in point why this would not be necessary. It is obvious how to accomplish this without this roundabout way.

Comment: @Tom Harrington: Thats exactly what i want to achieve. Edit an entity without context and if the user wants to save the modified entity insert it into my context. But after i save my context all string properties are stored as null.
Why is that ?

Comment: Why not just insert the entity into the context and delete if not used? Why all these hacks? See my edit.

Comment: @TristanHeitzinger-- like I said, post some more code, there's not enough information.

Comment: @TomHarrington Consider removing the down-vote after my most recent message edit.

Comment: @Mundi, I still disagree pretty strongly with the answer. I don't consider it to be "certainly more reasonable" to use the approach you describe. That's one approach, but there are others, and context-free managed objects are not by any means the "hacks" you describe them as being.

Comment: @TomHarrington Use my method and I guarantee that the string attributes will magically reappear. How is inserting into a nil context not a hack? Where is this documented? To be fair you should remove the down vote.

Comment: @Mundi, you can't make that guarantee, you don't have enough information (since Tristan still hasn't posted code). Regarding the use of a nil context, this situation is the exact (indeed the *only*) reason why `NSManagedObjectContext` has an `insertObject:` method. That method can't be used in any other situation. Also, see Apple's **ThreadedCoreData** sample code for an example of using a nil MOC when creating an object. I haven't removed the downvote because the answer is still highly inaccurate on multiple points.

Comment: @TomHarrington I'm reproducing this same issue, using `initWithEntity: insertIntoManagedObjectContext :` with a `nil` MOC and then using `insertObject:` later to add it to the MOC. Leads to `nil` properties on the managed object. Passing a MOC in the initial `init..` instead immediately fixes the issue (as this answer suggests). I'll add some code to the original question. Perhaps due to [`awakeFromInsert` not being called](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3868651/1265393)?